# trying to pull a total of all numbers in an array greater than 200 and display

Tags: vb.net

Good Morning, I have a dumb question, I have been at this for 20 hours and I need a little help Please
I have an array that has 15 names and numbers in it. I have the average, and I need to find out how many of entries are over 200 and display in a label.

what I have is not working:

```
Public Shared _intSizeOfArray As Integer = 14
Public Shared _strLastName(_intSizeOfArray) As String
'Private _strFirstName(_intSizeOfArray) As String
Public Shared _intCholesterolLevel(_intSizeOfArray) As Integer

Private Sub frmPatientCholesterollevels_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    '   This Load event reads the patient text file And initializes an instance
    '   of the StreamReader object.

    '   Declare Variables.
    Dim objReader As IO.StreamReader
    Dim strPatients As String = "patients.txt"
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
    Dim strFileError As String = "The file is not available. 
        Please restart the application when the file is availble"

    '   Verify the patient.txt file exists.
    If IO.File.Exists(strPatients) Then
        objReader = IO.File.OpenText(strPatients)

        '   Read the file line by line until the file is completed.
        Do While objReader.Peek <> -1
            _strLastName(intCount) = objReader.ReadLine()
            '_strFirstName(intCount) = objReader.ReadLine()
            _intCholesterolLevel(intCount) = Convert.ToInt32(objReader.ReadLine())
            intCount += 1
        Loop
        objReader.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox(strFileError, , "Error")
        Close()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnLabResults_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLabResults.Click

    '   This Click Event displays the number of patients who have an elevalted Cholesterol
    '   level over 200 and displays the information in the results form and copies the information
    '   to a USB Drive and a second text file located at e:\consult.txt.  It also displays the
    '   average cholesterol rate of the complete patient text file.

    '   Declare variables.
    Dim intPatientAverage As Double
    Dim intEvelatedLevel As Integer


    For intIAverage As Integer = 0 To _intCholesterolLevel.Length - 1
        intPatientAverage = intPatientAverage + _intCholesterolLevel(intIAverage)
    Next
    intPatientAverage = intPatientAverage / _intCholesterolLevel.Length
    For intIEvelated As Integer = 0 To _intCholesterolLevel.Length - 1
        intEvelatedLevel = intEvelatedLevel < 200(intIEvelated)
    Next




    'display the labels with the results

    lblAveragePatients.Text = "The Average Cholesterol Level for Today is: " &
        FormatNumber(intPatientAverage, 1) & "."
    lblElveatedLevel.Text = "The Number of Patients With a Cholesterol Level Above 200 is: " &
        FormatNumber(intEvelatedLevel, 1) & "."

End Sub

Thank you for any suggestions you can give me.
```

Pastor Ron

Comment: Hi Pastor, Hopefully my answer below should work for you. I hope you don't mind me saying, but there are more readable ways of writing this code, and it would be easier to maintain later on.  I'd be happy to help you - No pressure though. Instead of using 3 arrays for patient information, you could create a `Structure` to hold the patient's information, and one `List` of each patient's details. That way, you would be able to re-write your loops using `For Each` and not have to remember the `array.length-1` stuff. I'd be glad to help - just email me at the address in my user profile here

Comment: Two things though - what format is your "patients.txt" file in? I'm assuming that you are able to read all the data just fine. If you're getting any error, maybe you could edit your question to include these errors. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the logic in this loop needs a little work. :)

```
For intIEvelated As Integer = 0 To _intCholesterolLevel.Length - 1
    intEvelatedLevel = intEvelatedLevel < 200(intIEvelated)
Next
```

Try this.

```
    For intIEvelated As Integer = 0 To _intCholesterolLevel.Length - 1
        Dim patientCholesterolLevel As Integer = _intCholesterolLevel(intIEvelated)
        If patientCholesterolLevel > 200 Then
            intEvelatedLevel += 1
        End If
    Next
```

Hopefully, it should work.

Comment: David God Bless You.  You are a wonderful man and my prayers are with you and your family.  I worked perfectly.I have been trying to figure that out since Thursday, I will email you. the Professor has us using Visual Basic 2010 so everything is kind of outdated.  Now all I need to is figure out how to take the results from the above and send them to a text file on USB Drive.  I have to admit this is by far the worst assignment in the 6 weeks I have been at it.   Again.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Kind comments @RonEHillsJr. On another note: using VS2010 doesn't have nothing to do with the code above...

Comment: Thanks. Hehe. I think - your professor's knowledge is a bit out of date. The code you're writing smacks of VB6 - so I'm guessing that this is what he has taught you. For example - these days, using the underscore for local variables is frowned upon a little - it makes the code less readable. Ah well.. as long as you're enjoying the course - thats the main thing. :)